# How to solve the differential equation: yy''+2y'''=0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve yy''+2y'''=0 with B.Cs y(0)=y'(0)=0 & y'(∞)=1 ? Can somebody please hint at some substitution or refer any text related to these type of ode?

Comment: Dear Moo. B.Cs are correct !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you update the question and show your attempts?

Answer (score 2):

**NOT A FINAL ANSWER TO THE QUESTION**

First, we use the substitution $v=y',u=y$.

We have: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y'}{\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}y'}{\mathrm{d}x}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}}=\frac{y''}{y'}=\frac{y''}{v}$$

So $$y''=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}v$$

And: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2v}{\mathrm{d}u^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}\right)}{\mathrm{d}u}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{y''}{y'}\right)}{\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{y''}{y'}\right)}{\mathrm{d}x}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}}=\frac{\left(\frac{y'''y'-\left(y''\right)^2}{\left(y'\right)^2}\right)}{y'}=\frac{y'''v-\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}v\right)^2}{v^3}$$

So $$y'''=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2v}{\mathrm{d}u^2}v^2+\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}\right)^2v$$

Plugging in the above pair of expressions for $y''$ and $y'''$ along with $y=u$ (which holds by definition) into the original differential equation, we get: $$2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2v}{\mathrm{d}u^2}v^2+2\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}\right)^2v+\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}uv=0$$

Dividing through by $v$ and denoting $\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2v}{\mathrm{d}u^2}$ by $v'$ and $v''$, respectively: $$2v''v+2(v')^2+v'u=0$$

And this way, we have reduced the order of the differential equation by $1$. We can go further. First, divide through the second-order equation by $v'\sqrt v$: $$2\frac{v''\sqrt v}{v'}+2\frac{v'}{\sqrt v}+\frac{u}{\sqrt v}=0$$

Now, we employ the substitution $w=2\mathrm{ln}(u)-\mathrm{ln}(v),z=2\mathrm{ln}(v')-\mathrm{ln}(v)$.

It is immediate that $e^{\frac{w}{2}}=\frac{u}{\sqrt v}$ and $e^{\frac{z}{2}}=\frac{v'}{\sqrt v}$. Also: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}w}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(2\mathrm{ln}(v')-\mathrm{ln}(v)\right)}{\mathrm{d}\left(2\mathrm{ln}(u)-\mathrm{ln}(v)\right)}=\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(2\mathrm{ln}(v')-\mathrm{ln}(v)\right)}{\mathrm{d}u}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(2\mathrm{ln}(u)-\mathrm{ln}(v)\right)}{\mathrm{d}u}}=\frac{2\frac{v''}{v'}-\frac{v'}{v}}{2\frac{1}{u}-\frac{v'}{v}}$$$$=\frac{2\frac{v''\sqrt v}{v'}-\frac{v'}{\sqrt v}}{2\frac{\sqrt v}{u}-\frac{v'}{\sqrt v}}=\frac{2\frac{v''\sqrt v}{v'}-e^{\frac{z}{2}}}{2e^{-\frac{w}{2}}-e^{\frac{z}{2}}}$$

Rearranging and plugging everything back into the second-order equation, we get: $$\left(2e^{-\frac{w}{2}}-e^{\frac{z}{2}}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}w}+3e^{\frac{z}{2}}+e^{\frac{w}{2}}=0$$ Finally, a first-order equation. It is still an extremely unfriendly equation, though. We may rectify this with an additional substitution, $s=e^{\frac{z}{2}}, t=e^{-\frac{w}{2}}$. We then have: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(e^{\frac{z}{2}}\right)}{\mathrm{d}\left(e^{-\frac{w}{2}}\right)}=\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(e^{\frac{z}{2}}\right)}{\mathrm{d}w}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(e^{-\frac{w}{2}}\right)}{\mathrm{d}w}}=-\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}w}e^{\frac{z}{2}}}{e^{-\frac{w}{2}}}=-\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}w}s}{t}$$ Rearranging and substituting, once again, we get: $$(s-2t)\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}+3\frac{s^2}{t}+\frac{s}{t^2}=0$$

Finally, substitute $p=s-2t$ and leave $t$ as it is (I'm going to skip a bunch of working here): $$\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{3}{t}p+\left(14+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)+\left(12t+\frac{2}{t}\right)\frac{1}{p}=0$$

This is a Chini equation.

You can find some links in the accepted answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41177/a-nonlinear-first-order-ordinary-differential-equation-ytnat-fracdyt). But this particular case of the Chini equation does not look like it'll have a clean solution. This exercise in reduction/ simplification of the differential equation serves a couple of purposes.

First, you may be able to find references on solving the final equation (or, at least, bona fide approximations), as it is a previously studied type. Once you have something of a solution to the final equation, you should be able to reverse (at least, partially) the substitutions.

Secondly, even if you are not able to solve it in the general, these reduced differential still provide different ways of looking at the problem that can lend to better solution guessing.

For instance, if you look at the second-order equation, $2v''v+2(v')^2+v'u=0$, you may easily guess that setting $v$ equal to a quadratic in $u$ may solve the equation (for some suitable parameters). You'd be right. And this guess will give you a solution to the original equation, $y'=\frac{6}{x+D}$. Making similar guesses based on observations about other versions of the equation may yield solutions that conform more to the requirements of your question.

In any case, I hope this answer gives you an appreciation for how difficult finding closed-form solutions (if they even exist) to an 'average' differential equation can be. And this one was still relatively amenable to partial simplification.

By the way, some of the substitutions used were pure ansatzes. But others used a working knowledge of the [theory of Lie point symmetries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_point_symmetry). You can find many resources for the basics of how to use symmetry methods online.

Note: if there any mistakes in the answer, feel free to edit in the corrections or comment them

**EDIT:** A final substitution of $q=\frac{1}{p}$ turns the equation into an [Abel equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation_of_the_first_kind) which does seem to really have [a closed-form solution](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/), although, given its complexity and the amount of reverse-substitutions that would need to be performed, on top of having to solve for (or, more likely, approximate) the unknown constants to satisfy the boundary conditions, a numerical solution (like the one presented in Robert Israel's answer) would probably be more appropriate for this problem.

Comment: Dear Cardioid_Ass_22. Thanks for your nice comment.

Comment: @hassanali Appreciate it. In case you're still after a closed-form solution, I have added an edit at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: This is an impressive work. Thanks for providing such an answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you. It did take quite a while to put all the parts together.

Comment: Dear Cardioid_Ass_22. I don't know how to correct the boundary conditions for final equation. Abel equation looks like complicated. Do you have a simple example that is solved using the Abel equation?

Comment: @JimJ Unfortunately, I have never done work with the Abel equation. It was just that, after looking through many versions of the initial diff eq (mostly just the reduced differential equations in my answer), only the last two forms fit into already studied classes of diff eqs, namely Chini and Abel equations. And out of those two, only the Abel equation seems to have a known analytic solution. The biggest issue is that, if you want a closed form solution, you may not get a much better option than solving the complex Abel equation. (1/2)

Comment: @JimJ It may be the case that the boundary conditions simplify the problem significantly, but even teasing that out will likely be very difficult. I did put quite a lot of thought into this problem, but I don't honestly think chasing a closed-form solution is worth it. As I said in my edit, a numerical approach seems more suited to this problem. Nevertheless, great on you if you still have the conviction to see through the closed-form solution to the end. That takes a kind of courage (one that I don't have). Good luck. (2/2)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a closed-form solution, and I don't know if this will help.  But it looks like  with initial conditions $y(0)=0, y'(0)=0, y''(0)=2c$ you have a series solution of the form 
$$ y(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i c^{i+1} x^{2+3i}
$$
where the first few $a_i$ are 
$$ 1, -\frac1{60}, \frac{11}{20160}, -\frac{5}{266112}, \frac{9299}{14529715200}, -\frac{1272379}{59281238016000}$$
That is, $y(x) = cx^2 g(c x^3)$ for some $g$.  For this to be true, $g$ must satisfy 
$$ 54 t^2 g'''(t) + (9 t^2 g(t) + 216 t) g''(t) + (18 t g(t) + 120) g'(t) + 2 g(t)^2 =0$$

EDIT:
It appears (from numerical solution) that in the case $c=1$ we have $y(x) \sim 3.31 x$ as $x \to \infty$.  If that is true, then $g(t) \sim 3.31/t^{1/3}$ as $t \to \infty$, so to get $y(x) \sim x^2/2$ we'd want $c \approx  3.31^{-3/2} \approx 0.166$.
 Indeed, with $c = 0.166$, Maple's numerical solution gives us $y'(1000) \approx 0.999884746627945$.

Comment: But your B.Cs is different with above equation B.Cs !

Comment: Hopefully if $c$ is chosen correctly, you will have your $y'(\infty) = 1$.

Comment: In fact, I am looking for a closed-form solution.

Comment: Well, I'm doubtful that you'll find one.